# how to disappear label after 1 week for django template

Tags: django, if-statement, django-models, django-views, django-templates

lets think you have a blog with entrys. 
You want that the newly created entry has a label "new" and you want that this "new" label should disappear after 1 week from ceated_date.

What kind of way would you follow. I try this in django template. 
Thank you

Comment: I would compare **`NOW`** and **`ceated_date`**

Answer (score 1):

What I like to do is to create property of model. This is example of two properties that I have in my models:

```
active_from = models.DateField(default=now)
active_to = models.DateField(null=True)

@property
def is_past_due(self):
    return date.today() > self.active_to

@property
def is_now(self):
    return self.active_from < date.today() < self.active_to
```

I think that you can get idea how to create property from this example, and adopt to your needs. After you have this, it is simple to check in template like (phase is one instance of the model):

```
{% if phase.is_past_due %}
    <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle animated fadeIn infinite alternate" style="color: red;"></i>
{% endif %}
```